# Mail message with foreach loop isn't working in PHP

Tags: foreach, swiftmailer, php

I want to mail the details of a web shop order and therefore need to use a foreach loop to construct my message. I thought the message below would work, but it doesn't. How can I make this work?

```
              '<table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column-product"><strong>Productomschrijving</strong></td>
                    <td class="column-aantal"><strong>Aantal</strong></td>
                    <td class="column-prijs"><strong>Prijs</strong></td>
                </tr>'.foreach($shopper_cart as $item) {
                    $value = $item['aantal'] * $item['price'];
                    $sum += $value;.'
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$item["product_id"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$item["aantal"].'</td>
                    <td>€'.$item["aantal"] * $item["price"].'</td>
                </tr>
                </table>'.};
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is never a good description of an issue. Describe what you want your code to do and what it does instead.

Comment: You can't just put a `foreach` into the middle of a string like that. That's fundamentally broken syntax. It just doesn't work like that.

Comment: I need to sum up an order in an email. And I need a way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just put a `foreach` into the middle of a string like that. That's fundamentally broken syntax. It just doesn't work like that.

The best solution for you is to declare the loop as a separate function, like so:

```
function cartItemTableRows($shopper_cart) {
    $output = '';
    foreach($shopper_cart as $item) {
        $value = $item['aantal'] * $item['price'];
        $sum += $value;
        $output .='<tr>
                    <td>'.$item["product_id"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$item["aantal"].'</td>
                    <td>€'.$item["aantal"] * $item["price"].'</td>
                </tr>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Now you can put a call to your new function into the existing code where you're building the string:

```
$tableHTML = '<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="column-product"><strong>Productomschrijving</strong></td>
        <td class="column-aantal"><strong>Aantal</strong></td>
        <td class="column-prijs"><strong>Prijs</strong></td>
    </tr>'.cartItemTableRows($shopper_cart).'
</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `.` to join strings together. You'd need to do something along the lines of this:

```
          $order_details_table = '<table>
            <tr>
                <td class="column-product"><strong>Productomschrijving</strong></td>
                <td class="column-aantal"><strong>Aantal</strong></td>
                <td class="column-prijs"><strong>Prijs</strong></td>
            </tr>';

            // append a row to the table string for each order item
            foreach($shopper_cart as $item) {
                $value = $item['aantal'] * $item['price'];
                $sum += $value;
                $order_details_table .= '
                <tr>
                  <td>'.$item["product_id"].'</td>
                  <td>'.$item["aantal"].'</td>
                  <td>€'.$item["aantal"] * $item["price"].'</td>
                </tr>';
            }

            $order_details_table .= '</table>';
```

Then you can use `$order_details_table` where you want this table to appear.

The `.=` works a bit like `.`, but it appends a string to a variable already containing a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed a foreach loop in a string like that. You need to break out of the string, then run your foreach().

```
$emailBody =  '<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="column-product"><strong>Productomschrijving</strong></td>
                        <td class="column-aantal"><strong>Aantal</strong></td>
                        <td class="column-prijs"><strong>Prijs</strong></td>
                    </tr>';
foreach($shopper_cart as $item) {
       $emailBody .= '<tr>
                        <td>'.$item["product_id"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$item["aantal"].'</td>
                        <td>€'.$item["aantal"] * $item["price"].'</td>
                    </tr>';
}
          $emailBody .=  '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

here:
    $value = $item['aantal'] * $item['price'];
you should be Changed like this： 
    $value = $item["aantal"] * $item["price"];
because your Single quotation marks as delimiters

Answer (score 0):

As @Spudley says you can't concatenate a foreach like that. You need to separate it from the string. You may also want to initialize the `$sum` var before adding to it.

The code should look something like this:

```
$table = '<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="column-product"><strong>Productomschrijving</strong></td>
        <td class="column-aantal"><strong>Aantal</strong></td>
        <td class="column-prijs"><strong>Prijs</strong></td>
    </tr>';

$sum = 0;
foreach($shopper_cart as $item) {
    $value = $item['aantal'] * $item['price'];
    $sum += $value;
    $table .= '<tr>
        <td>'.$item["product_id"].'</td>
        <td>'.$item["aantal"].'</td>
        <td>€'.$item["aantal"] * $item["price"].'</td>
    </tr>';
}

$table .= '</table>';
```